# correct use of 'construct' when designing classes

Tags: php, oop

I am new to object oriented programming and writing some of my first classes for a PHP application.

In some of the simpler classes, I declare a `function __construct()`, and inside of that function, call certain class methods. In some cases, I find myself instantiating the class in my app, and not needing to do anything with the resultant object because the class's `__construct()` called the methods, which did their job, leaving me nothing left to do with the class.

This just doesn't feel right to me. Seems goofy that I have a new object that I never do anything with.

Again, I'll stress this is only the case for some of my more simple classes. In the more complicated ones, I do use class methods via the object and outside of `__construct()`.

Do I need to rethink the way I coding things, or am I ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the constructor is used to create a new instance of a class, and to do any necessary setup on that class. If you're just creating the class and leaving it, that does seem a bit of a waste. Why not, for instance, use static functions in the class as an organizational tool and just call them(or a function that calls them) instead of constructing a new instance that you'll never use?

Comment: Damn, you beat me, I was just about to say the exact same thing. xD

Comment: Ha, that's been a recurring problem to me. I always get beaten to the questions that I can answer. :P I just got lucky for once! :D

Answer (score 2):

> This just doesn't feel right to me. Seems goofy that I have a new object that I never do anything with.

Yes, that should raise a red flag.

In general, you should not let constructors have any side effects; They are meant for initialising the state of the object - not for anything else. There are of course exceptions to this rule, but in general it's a good guide line. You should also abstain from doing any heavy calculations in the constructor. Move that to a method instead.

[Side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) are many things - Changes to global variables or static (class) variables; output to the environment (For example calls to `print()`, `header()` or `exit()`); calls to a database or other external service and even changes to the state of other objects.

A side effect free function is also called a "pure" function - as opposed to a *procedure*, which is a function that has side effects. It's a good practise to explicitly separate pure functions from procedures (and perhaps even label them as such).